# Listing files under a specific folder from remote repository with JGit

Tags: jgit

I'm trying to list files from HEAD from a remote repository (Github). I read examples from the JGit documentation, but most of the time these are referencing to a local repository.
The only piece of code I found about remote repository is:

```java
Collection<Ref> refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
    .setHeads(true)
    .setTags(true)
    .setRemote("https://github/example/example.git")
    .call();

for (Ref ref : refs) {
    System.out.println("Ref: " + ref);
}
```

But this code is just listing references, like HEAD. Could anyone help listing files from a subfolder inside my remote repository?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

LsRemoteCommand is the counterpart of `git ls-remote` and only lists references of a remote repository. In order to list files contained in a repository, you have to first clone the repository .

For example:

```java
Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
  .setURI( "https://github.com/eclipse/jgit.git" )
  .setDirectory( "/path/to/repo" )
  .call();
```

See this link for more on cloning repositories with JGit:  http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/

Comment: Is this downloading all files to local file system?

Comment: Clone downloads the entire history of the repository and by default checks out the main branch (usually 'master') into the work directory.